# Django switch database user

Tags: django

Assume I got different database users, and each of them have different permissions (already settled in db side). How can I switch between different db users?

```
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': '****',
        'USER': '****', # i got several users here and want to switch them
        'PASSWORD': '****',
        'HOST': '*****',
        'PORT': '***',
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to use multiple databases (even if they have the same host) and just change the user per database.

[Django Multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/multi-db/)

PS. Maybe you have a good reason to use multiple users but I think it would be a better idea to just have one database user and handle permissions to the different tables use the Django permission system.